# How to create ENUM in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, database, enums, sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from migrate import *

meta = MetaData()
race_enums = ('asian','mideastern','black','nativeamerican','indian','pacific','hispanic','white','other');
profiles_profiles = Table(
    'profiles_profiles', meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key = True),
    Column('user_id', Integer, nullable=False, unique=True),
    Column('race', Enum, race_enums),
    Column('summary', Text, nullable= True),
    Column('my_life', Text, nullable= True),
    Column('to_do', Text, nullable= True),
    Column('favs', Text, nullable= True),
    Column('created_at', DateTime, nullable=True),
    Column('updated_at', DateTime, nullable=True)
)

def upgrade(migrate_engine):
    meta.bind = migrate_engine
    profiles_profiles.create()
    pass

def downgrade(migrate_engine):
    meta.bind = migrate_engine
    profiles_profiles.drop()
    pass
```

When I manage.py upgrade this, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_set_parent_with_dispatch'
```

Answer (score 28):

You need pass `race_enum` as an argument for `Enum`, not `Column`

You can either pass in your `tuple` as whole

```
Column('race', Enum('asian','mideastern','black','nativeamerican','indian','pacific','hispanic','white','other'))
```

or use `*` to unpack `race_enums`:

```
Column('race', Enum(*race_enums))
```

Comment: I'm having trouble setting the Enum value in a similar situation. How would you set the value of `race` for the `profiles_profiles` table? Does it simply take a string?

Comment: @TonyH I am not quite sure what you mean by "set the value"

Comment: I believe he means insert a record. @Wondercricket