# Create DB tables with different user types and authenticate user with username and password

Tags: python, django, database, models

I am stuck with the schema creation so could you provide me an idea to implement this scenario

i do have 4 types of users Student, Teacher, Parent and Admin

i have tried to create 4 tables for each users and a table for username, password and tokens but i am not able to relate this table to the users because more than one user cannot have same username

What i want is i need to authenticate each user withe their user name and password and the Student table might be having relationship with Parent table !!!!

so while authenticating i need to know which type of user he/she is

i am using python Django 1.9

Comment: if would be helpful if you can show what you have done =)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating four separate tables, you can simply add a field which will reflect the `user_type` of the user.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):

    ...
    [other model fields]
    ...

    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('student', 'Student'),
        ('teacher', 'Teacher'),
        ('parent', 'Parent'),
        ('admin', 'Admin'),
    )

    user_type = models.CharField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=7)
```

By doing this, all users will have unique usernames and they will become easy to manage too.

You can check type of user just by accessing its `user_type`, it'll return one of this text values "*Student, Teacher, Parent and Admin*". So you'll be able to handle business logic for different user types.

Comment: So can i implement relation between Parent user and student user also ? and the teacher user might have more fields so can i add it as optional fields in the User model ?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can add optional fields depending on type of user. I would suggest to create something like `Profile` model so that your `User` model remains clean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Django authentication system : 
[Using the Django authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#using-the-django-authentication-system)
 and for each category of user you can use : [Groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#groups)

> `django.contrib.auth.models.Group` models are a generic way of categorizing users so you can apply
>   permissions, or some other label, to those users. A user can belong to
>   any number of groups.

Answer (score 0):

Creating four tables is not the correct way.
Alternatively you can ,

```
class User():

    id = Column(PrimaryKey)
    username = Column(String, constraints)
    password = Column(String, constraints)
    usertype = Column(Enum('student','teacher','parent','admin'))
```

-- The code is only for representation .

For setting user role , you can use the Enum Property. In case you are using SQLALchemy , check this out

[How to create ENUM in SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644292/how-to-create-enum-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: So can i implement relation between Parent user and student user also ? and the teacher user might have more fields so can i add it as optional fields in the User model ?

Comment: Adding it to the user class is not advisable. As mentioned below you can use a Profile class and implement a one to one relation.